# angular universal on iisnode cant find view error

Tags: iis, angular6, angular-universal, iisnode

server side rendering is working good on my local machine
using `npm run serve:ssr`

i want to upload it to my iis 8 server
this is what i did

building the app on my local machine:

```
npm run build:ssr
```

upload the content to my server (iisnode installed)

content folder:

[image]

web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <match url="/*" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

result: (i notice path is wrong)
what him i missing here ?

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\dist\browser"
    at Function.render (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:41859:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:51402:7)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:113:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:43645:5)
    at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:43393:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:43368:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:43645:5)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:42868:22
    at param (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:42941:14)
    at param (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\universal\server.js:42952:14)
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any Solution for this....???

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following line (in bold) in your server.js file?

> app.set('view engine', 'html');
>
> **app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));**